# mat-select change event not trigger in setvalue angular 13 reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6, angular-material-5

Using the mat-select inside the form-group

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-select formControlName="formula" id="formula">
       <mat-option [value]="metricFormula.TotalCount">{{l('TotalCount')}}</mat-option>
       <mat-option [value]="metricFormula.Sum">{{l('Sum')}}</mat-option>
       <mat-option [value]="metricFormula.Average">{{l('Average')}}</mat-option>
       <mat-option [value]="metricFormula.Percentage">{{l('Percentage')}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the ts file setting the value to form control `formula`, doesn't trigger the change event

```
 get f() { return this.formGroup.controls; }

 private formBuild(): void {
        this.f.formula.setValue(metricFormula.Average);
}
```

Change event code doesn't get called, however, works on manually selecting the value from list

```
onChanges(): void {
    this.f.formula?.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.formBuild();
        this.onChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this onChanges() method ?

Comment: ngOnInit() method

Comment: You need subscribe to valueChanges **before** call to onChanges (a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbnbse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) with your code)

Comment: Please ensure that form has been initialised before calling onChanges inside ngOnInit... else it will not subscribe it ever on the valueOnChanges .. So what you can do is first create form inside ngOnInit and then call onChanges()..

Answer (score 0):

I have to implement `AfterViewInit`  and worked for me

```
    export class MetricConfigureComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.f.formula.setValue(//Some value of that type);
        });
      }
    }
```